# Why using _represents_?

Tags: grammar, verbs, relative-clauses, grammaticality-in-context

I think it is **representing** instead of **represents**.

Can Anyone explain to me?

> **You can see sample-project *represents* whichever name you want to give to it**. In the book, and I don’t mean
>   to be funny, we are going call it sample-project. However, it would be wise if you pick your own name. You
>   will need a unique name later in the book when we create our Facebook login via Socialite.

Comment: Can you give more context? Where is this from?

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is fine as written: the subordinator *that* has been omitted, as it often is:

> You can see <s>that</s> *sample-project* represents whichever name you want to give to it.

Comment: Can I use **representing** or **to represent** or **represented**?

Comment: *You can see X representing Y* would mean you have the opportunity to watch the representation, and  *represented* would cast the observation in the past tense; it is unlikely that either of these is what the author means. You will occasionally see *to be* with *see*, but it's very clunky; other infinitivals don't work.

Comment: What is difference between 1 and 2.?

_1.You can see sample-project represents whichever name you want to give to it_  .

_2.You can see sample-project **which** represents whichever name you want to give to it._

Comment: sorry, I edited, I deleted _that_.Can You explain for more details please?

Comment: *See* may take either a noun phrase or a clause as its complement: *I see X* or *I see (that) X does Y*. The sentence in your Question has the second form: what is seen is the fact that 'sample-project' represents a name. The sentence in your Comment above has the first form: what is seen is just 'sample-project'; the fact that 'sample-project' represents a name is additional information about 'sample-project'.

Comment: so, Are Both sentence _1 and 2_ the same meaning? Is there difference between them?

Comment: They refer to the same situation, but they do different things. One calls your attention to a fact about 'sample-project'; the other calls your attention to 'sample-project' and mentions a fact about it. In context, it's the fact that's important, not the name, so the original sentence is better than your paraphrase.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64542/discussion-between-pham-van-duc-and-stoneyb).